# Restyling site without going offline

Tags: offline

I want to renew my site without going offline
I thought these steps:

1. Copy all the files and db from remote to local (on wamp)
2. Make the changes
3. Move from local to remote

is this the easiest way to do this? There are better ways?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to set up a development site on your local machine.

The easiest way to do this would be to first download all the files from the live server then make a database backup.

On your local machine, set up your environment, drop your files in place then create a new database using the backup you just made from the live site.

Update your config and database files as necessary to use the new paths and database connection on your local machine.

Do your work.

The tricky bit comes next. Depending on the changes you're making you will need to restore the files and data to the live server.

If no content has changed on the live server (including member registrations etc) then you can simply replace the database and upload your new files.

If content on the live server has changed then it's going to be harder as you need to get the databases in sync somehow and get your new fields, add-on data onto the live server while retaining the site content.

If the changes are just to templates then you should be fine. Equally if just a few new fields and add-ons were added then it might be easier just to recreate them on the live server (after taking another backup of course).

There may well be a better way to get the databases 'in sync' by doing some kind of 'merge'. I'd be interested in hearing them myself!

Answer (score 2):

You might like to check out [FocusLab's master config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config) approach, which lets you setup multiple environments. That way you get local, dev and live environments setup. Make changes to your local version, then when you're ready just deploy to live site manually or using something like Git.

Comment: Is it compatible with ee1?